# Stored procedure inserting only one rows after the loop is over in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which calculates and has 3 rows for inserting the data into the table. So After loop I am trying to insert those rows in the table. But only first row is getting inserted into the table.

Below is link of my procedure.

[Procedure link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1fa7ea3970d24ee06fdba4882ee239ff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kidding? A ~1.000 lines of unformatted procedure?

Anyway, here you go: as insert is **out of the loop*, it executes only once. Move it into the loop (i.e. before the `END LOOP` statement).